# Factor/level error in mixed model

Tags: r, glm, mixed-models

I am running a mixed model on something akin to this data:

```
df<-data.frame(stage=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c"),
nematode=c("fn","fn","bn","bn","fn","fn","bn","bn","fn","fn","bn","bn"),
id2=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
value=c(1,0,0,2,3,1,1,2,0,0,0,2))
```

The model I am trying to fit is:

```
stage.id <- function(x) round(summary(glmer(value ~ stage + (1 | id2),family="poisson", data = x))$coefficients[2, c(1, 2, 4)], 3)
models.id0  <- ddply(tree2, .(stage, nematode), stage.id)
```

However, when I run this, I continually get an error:

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
>   contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

which doesn't make sense to me given that I've used the nlevels() command on each of the factors (df$stage and df$nematode) and they are 3 and 2, respectively. Any sense what might be awry?

Answer (score 3):

You have `stage` as a fixed effect in your model, but you're trying to fit the model for every combination of `stage` and `nematode` (`ddply(tree2, .(stage, nematode), ...)`). Thus in each chunk of the data there's only a single `stage` value, which causes the error.

You could:

- apply only over `nematode` values, i.e. `ddply(tree2,.(nematode), ...)`
- leave `stage` out of your model, i.e. fit the model `value ~ 1 + (1 | id2)`

According to your comment ("my goal is to compare the stages for each of the types of nematodes. I.e., for each type of nematode (e.g., `bn`) do the stages differ"), you want the former solution (apply only over `nematode` values).

Comment: I should say that my goal is to compare the stages for each of the types of nematodes. I.e., for each type of nematode (e.g., bn) do the stages differ. Either one of your suggestions seems to yield the same results. I believe they will allow me to determine whether the stages are significantly different for each type of nematode, but is there any way to do any sort of post-hoc comparison test to figure out which stages differ for each type of nematode? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I think I got it:

     bn<-subset(df,nematode=="bn")
     bn.mod<-glmer(value ~ stage + (1 | id2),  family="poisson", data = bn)
     bn.tuk<-glht(bn.mod,mcp(stage="Tukey"))
     summary(bn.tuk)
     tuk.cld <- cld(bn.tuk)   # letter-based display
     opar <- par(mai=c(1,1,1.5,1))
     plot(tuk.cld)
     par(opar)

Comment: But, if I do that then my comparison tests find significant differences in nematodes between stages for nematodes the mixed model did not find significantly different.  I.e., the mixed model found that bn did not differ between the stages (p=0.34) whereas if I run the post hoc Tukey test, it finds significant differences (p<0.01)...That said, this is more of a question for Cross Validated...

Comment: Maybe I am misinterpreting the mixed model results?

Comment: maybe.  We'd kind of need to see the full (even reproducible) example to know ...